# Steam API get current user status

Tags: php, steam

I'm trying to use the steam web API to show the current status of ONE steam user if they are (online, away, offline, looking to trade) etc and have setup a PHP switch as follows:

```
<?
$status = $steamprofile['personastate'];
switch($status) {
    case 0:
        echo "offline!";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "online!";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "Busy.";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "Away.";
        break;
    case 4:
        echo "Snooze.";
        break;
    case 5:
        echo "Looking to trade.";
        break;
    case 6:
        echo "Looking to play.";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Unknown status";
}
echo $status;
?>
```

It works great but only shows the user status when logged unto the site and not simply when the user is online/away/offline etc on the steam platform.

I'm wondering if anyone know how to fix so it displays the current user status on steam, not just if they are logged in on the web site.

Comment: it should do that already? fetching player summaries returns the correct code for me  https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29
do you mean the status is only displayed when logged into your site or steamcommunity.com?

Comment: Yes it only displays when logged in. If I do login on the website running steam Web API It returns "online!" otherwise simply offline. I'm trying to make it so when you you login on the steam say on a PC, it will show you as online, not requiring you to login to the website to show as online or X status.